# NSNumberFormatter returning nil if unexpected chars in string

Tags: ios, null, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to convert user input of a number from a `UITextView` (not a `UITextField`, for reasons that would take too long to go into) string into a number.  While this has presented no problems when the user enters data via the decimal keyboard on the iPhone, with a bluetooth keyboard (or using the keyboard in the simulator, the user can enter non-numeric characters, or can hit the return key. This causes the `NSNumberFormatter` to return `nil`, which of course does me no good.

I am trying to figure out how to deal with this. Should I make a filter that extracts just that part of the input string that has allowable characters in it? Can anyone recommend an elegant/efficient way to deal with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter;
if (numberFormatter==nil) {
        numberFormatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [numberFormatter setLenient:YES];
}
self.value = [numberFormatter numberFromString:self.valueTextView.text];
```

As I said, if the user enter `42`, or `42.5`, this works fine, but if she enters `42.5<Return>` (which can only be done from the keyboard) then `self.value` is `nil`. ***Note:** I added the `setLenient` mode to try and cope with the problem, but to no avail.*

I've checked other answers on Stack Overflow (a number of people have asked similar questions), but the answers I found just confirm that yes, `NSNumberFormatter` will only parse, not validate, and if it cannot parse it will return nil. This doesn't solve the problem. How do others deal with this? It must be a common problem...

Comment: What do you want it to return instead if the string is not numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`. In its implementation you should create the text that would exist if you allow the edit to complete and try getting a number from that text with your formatter. If you get a number, allow the edit. If not, refuse the edit.